# Why isn't an object created using executeScript in Protractor

Tags: javascript, angularjs, protractor, angularjs-e2e

I have this code inside a `describe` in a protractor script that tests an angular js app.

```
beforeEach(function() {
  browser.get('index.html#/device_list');
  browser.executeScript("chrome.bluetooth = {};");
  browser.executeScript("console.log('test')");
  browser.executeScript("alert('test')");
});
```

Without this code the tests run and fail as expected. When I add this code and run the script the object isn't created, the console log isn't printed but an alert is created (and throws an async error as expected).

I have tried it without the alert and their is still no object or log.

Why is this? Is it possible to create a simple object which can be used by a test using executeScript in protractor? If not is there another way of doing it that doesn't involve creating a service?

I'm using this code inside the Protractor script to look for the console log.

```
browser.manage().logs().get('browser').then(function(browserLog) {
    if(browserLog.length > 0) {
        console.log(browserLog);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Logging only shows error-level logs.

You'd need to do:

```
browser.executeScript("console.error('test')");
```

Answer (score 1):

`executeScript` runs in the browser. If you are expecting to see the log in your node process it will not be there. It I will in you browser's log.

Comment: This explains why the object isn't created as this is being used in node. I have updated the question to show how I am checking for the console log. I should see it there no?